# Chrome does not draw in DOM sometimes but Firefox does

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

The thing is that our loading animation image isn't showing in Chrome sometimes (sometimes it does) but it always does in Firefox.

The code is really simple:

```
initLoadingAnimation: function () {
            var $body = $("body");
            $(document).on({
                ajaxStart: function () {
                    $body.addClass("loading");
                },
                ajaxStop: function () {
                    $body.removeClass("loading");
                }
            });
        }
```

And CSS part:

```
/* Loading animation */
.loading_anim {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) url('../img/loading_anim_blue.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

body.loading .loading_anim {
    overflow: hidden;
}

body.loading .loading_anim {
    display: block;
}
```

I have a div in top of the body element with class "loading_anim".

It works perfectly in Firefox but it doesn't in Chrome. I've tried introducing the setTimeout(fn, 0) when calling this function but I still get the problem.

(When I put manually the class "loading" in the body element via developer tools  in Chrome the loading image appears)

Comment: Any errors in the dev console?

Comment: Probably cors issues as you accessing local resources?

Comment: @Patrick Console is clean :(

Comment: @whiterabbitj The problem is also ocurring in both of our domains

Comment: according to [the jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/): "This event is triggered if an Ajax request is started and no other Ajax requests are currently running.". Are you sure no other request is running?

Comment: @Kaddath As I said in the explanation, I don't think that this is a Jquery problem itself but a browser problem. Firefox triggers both ajaxStart and ajaxStop in every single AJAX call produced in the page

Comment: well yeah but as i can see you are accessing local resources (the gif) chrome is on happy about it. What is the URL of that gif is it stored locally?

Comment: @whiterabbitj I don't think that is producing the problem. We are using kendo and it also happened with the kendo.ui.progress function. It is stored locally, but I can manually change the class of the body element and the gif is shown.

Comment: @Kaddath the problem is not with the addition of the class but with the drawing of the gif in the screen. If I put manually the class into the body element I can see the gif perfectly.

Comment: @JavierPallarés how do you issue ajax calls? Are they `async: true`?

Comment: @Kaddath The events are firing since I can dinamically see in the body classes the "loading" one. The problem is with the drawing of the element in the moment that lane of code is executed.

Could it be a thread issue with CSS in Chrome?

Comment: @Benny There are a lot of AJAX calls, some async and some are not.

Comment: @JavierPallarés and Chrome's behavior is the same no matter what `async` is?

Comment: maybe thread issue with JS rather.. btw is the loading time very short? (shorter than the image to load for example?). I also sometimes noticed than when lot of JS processing is done (close to the "page not responding" popup), Chrome doesn't bother to update DOM from JS functions anymore, like he's waiting for the end. Had this with a counter that was supposed to show processed files count, works fine in Firefox, Chrome never updates the count until he's finished all processes..

Comment: @Benny Hmm, the loading animation stops working in all the web (our site is a single page application) suddenly. It happens when refreshing or moving between the different sections. No matter it is async or not.

Comment: @Kaddath The time can be short or long. The kendo.ui.progress function used to fail only in large AJAX requests (like uploading a big file) but with this method (the current one) it fails no matter the time is long or short.
We moved to the animation gif image because kendo was giving us problem, but I can see the problem is not with Kendo but with different browsers.

Comment: I'm still finding a solution for this.